# Bad request when trying to post to wcf rest 4 service

Tags: rest, jquery, wcf-rest

I am playing with the wcf 4.0 rest template and trying to get it to work with jquery.

I have created a new rest template project and added a webform into the same project just to get things simple.

I have slightly modfied the Create Method to look like this

```
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
    public string Create(SampleItem instance)
    {
        // TODO: Add the new instance of SampleItem to the collection
        return (instance.Id == 1) ? "1 was returned" : "something else was returned";
    }
```

Then from my webform I am using this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "/service1/",
              data: { "Id": 1,"StringValue": "String content"
              },
              success: function (data) {
                  $('.result').html(data);
              },
              error: function (error) {
                  $('.result').html(error)
               },
              dataType: "json",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
          });

      });
    </script>
    <div class="result"></div>
```

However fiddler is returning a 400 error telling me there is a request error. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 can also mean something in your service went wrong. Did you try to attach a debugger to the Rest-service? 
Tried to create a .Net-console application (create the request using HttpClient) and communicate with your service?

I ran into same error, after half hour of testing I saw just some error occured in the REST-service.